# iOS Detecting installed app on a webpage

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

When I go into youtube on a safari in iOS I have the widget offering me to open the installed app

How do they do that? I tried to debug the window, but probably it hides inside a minified js

Attaching a partial screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of [Apple's Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

You can add it on your own website by adding the following meta-tag:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

The `app-id` is the nine-digit number in between `id` and `?mt` in App Store URLs. `affiliate-data` and `app-argument` are optional. Check the documentation for more info.

It isn't supported on third-party browsers, like Chrome for iOS. In that case you will have to do it yourself or use scripts like these:

> https://github.com/ijason/Smart-App-Banners
>   https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner
>   http://kurtzenisek.com/p/smart-web-banner/

Comment: will this work for Chrome for iOS as well?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But there exists scripts that can fake it. (Added some links in the answer).

Comment: Thank you. Wish I have two votes.

Comment: Sorry, im not the questioner.

Comment: Done... sorry for the delay :) Thanks...

Comment: @johankj my ios app-id  have 10 digit number after id ane before ?mt in App Store URLs.so it will worked for me or not?

Comment: Yep, it should still work. Apple has just changed the format of the number of the years.